# Quick shifting chars of string

Tags: c, string

I have a string `This is a text` and I want to shift it to the left.
So, when I want it to shift for 2 positions, it should result in `is is a textTh`.

For some reason, I can't quite get there.

```
void rotLeft(char *s, unsigned int n)
{
    char *t = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
    int i;
    int ti = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i+=1)
    {
        t[ti] = s[i];
        ti +=1;
    }

    // + n should remove the n first chars?
    strcat(s + n, t);
}
```

Comment: AKA, you want to swap positions of characters

Comment: Is `n` the length of the string or the amount of shifting? If it's the first, then I assume the function rotates 1 char to the left. Note that `ti` and `i` have always the same value: both initialize to 0 and both increment by 1. This is not what you want. You want `ti` to be one step back from `i` so character at position 1 of s is copied into character at position 0 of t, character at position 2 to position 1, and so on.

Comment: @Farseer no, `s` is a pointer so `s+n` = `s + n*sizeof(*s)` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a temp variable, this rotates **ONCE**. `n` is the length of the string.

```
void rotLeft(char *s, int n)
{
    char temp;
    int i;
    temp = s[0];
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        s[i] = s[i+1];
    }
    s[n-1]=temp;

}
```

Comment: @IMX You understand it wrong. Pass length of the string as argument n, then it will rotate once. Call this function as much as you need.

Comment: But I don't need it to rotate once. I just need it to rotate for n (say 2) chars.

Comment: Then call this function twice!

Comment: No sorry, I actually +1 this, but somehow there was another answer that had a memory leak, but it disappeared so I must have accidentally posted it here :P sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
void rotLeft(char *s, unsigned int n)
{
    char *t;
    int l;

    l = strlen(s);
    t = (char *)malloc(n);
    strncpy (t,s,n);
    strncpy (s,s+n,l-n);
    strncpy (s+l-n,t,n);
    free (t);   
}
```

Just be carefull and not try to rotate more than the length of the string. Argument values are not checked against errors.

Comment: t = malloc(n + *1*); No need for cast, but you need to allocate enough space.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest constructing a new rotated string, not rotate the existing string in-place.

```
char *rotLeft(char *s, int n)
{
    char * t = malloc((strlen(s) + 1) * sizeof(char))
    strncpy(t, s + n, strlen(s) - n);
    strncpy(t + strlen(s) - n, s, n);
    s[strlen(s)] = '\0';
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Can you justify, why he shouldn't rotate in place?

Comment: I like my strings immutable, just my personal preference.

Comment: And you seem to like memory leaks as well, by allocating memory that you don't free, and as the allocation is performed within the function, someone that calls your function won't know that until he reads the source. If you don't like `s` to be altered, just add another argument to be your destination string.

Comment: Oh, I LOVE memory leaks! Seriously though, I assume a working knowledge of how C deals with memory, do I always have to spell out how to clean up after yourself? When writing a lib, it is common practice to put info like that in the doc string, you wouldn't have to read the sources. I don't have it here, deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the classic trick for rotating a string in-place without using temporary storage (aside from a single character). (A production version should check that the rotation amount is not too big.)

```
void reverse(char* s, size_t lo, size_t hi) {
  while(lo < hi) {
    char t = s[lo];
    s[lo++] = s[--hi];
    s[hi] = t;
  }
}

void rotate_left(char* s, size_t n) {
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  reverse(s, 0, n);
  reverse(s, n, len);
  reverse(s, 0, len);
}
```